# Cookies not showing up

Tags: reactjs, express, cookies, vercel

I am having trouble getting my express server to attach a cookie on login. Bellow is the code I have written, I recently deployed my react app on Vercel which is what is making requests to my express server which I am still running locally. Everything works as it should and cookies are attaches when I run the react app locally.

Thank you,

Express Server

```
router.post("/", (req, res) =>{
      const email = req.body.userName.toLowerCase()
      const pass = req.body.password
      db.query(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '${email}'`, async (err, result) => {
        if(result.rows.length === 1){
          let user = result.rows[0]
          bcrypt.compare(pass, user.password, (err, result) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            if(result === true){
              user.password = 'blocked'
              let token = jwt.sign({"tokenInfo": user, "userType": user.user_type}, secret, { algorithm: 'HS256'})
              return res.cookie('userId', token, {
                maxAge: 60000 * 60 * 2,
                httpOnly: false
              }).send({'message': "User Loged In", 'userType': user.user_type, 'userID': user.apaid})
            } else {
              return res.send({'message': 'Invalid Password', 'userType': 'false'})
            }
          })
        } else if(result.rows.length > 1) {
          res.send('WTF')
        } else {
          res.send({'message': 'Invalid User Name', 'userType': 'false'})
        }
        console.log(res.cookies)
      })
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Frontend and backend parts of your app should be served on the same domain in order to use cookies. If you created your app with `create-react-app` you can set up a proxy in your `package.json` file of your react app.

```
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "proxy": "http://*address of your locally running server eg:localhost:5000/*"
```

Comment: I added a proxy to http://localhost:3500 which is where my server is running and redeployed, I am still not getting any cookies. I am running nodemon to restart the server on edits.